# When calling POST method of Jersey client throws Already connected exception

Tags: java, jersey, apache-httpclient-4.x

Following is my code:

```
public TAPattern getVSTTAPattern(TAPattern vstpattern) throws IOException {

    System.out.println(vstpattern.getCar());
    System.out.println(vstpattern.getCategory());

    ConfigPropertyHandler configPropertyHandler = ConfigPropertyHandler.getInstance();
    ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
    HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic(configPropertyHandler.getTid(),
            configPropertyHandler.getPassword());
    System.out.println(configPropertyHandler.getPassword());
    System.out.println(configPropertyHandler.getTid());
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
    client.register(feature);


    WebTarget webTarget = client.target(configPropertyHandler.getVstUrl()).path(configPropertyHandler.getVstPath());
    System.out.println(webTarget.toString());
    System.out.println(configPropertyHandler.getVstUrl());
    System.out.println(configPropertyHandler.getVstPath());


    Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);

    Response response = invocationBuilder.header("Content-Type", "application/xml")
            .post(Entity.entity(vstpattern, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML));


    response.close();
    return response.readEntity(TAPattern.class);

}
```

Following is my stacktrace:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [RQMOSLCBridge] in context with path [/RQMOSLCBridge] threw exception [javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Already connected] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty(HttpURLConnection.java:3014)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector.setOutboundHeaders(HttpUrlConnector.java:348)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector.access$100(HttpUrlConnector.java:87)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector$3.getOutputStream(HttpUrlConnector.java:311)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commitStream(CommittingOutputStream.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commitStream(CommittingOutputStream.java:194)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commit(CommittingOutputStream.java:262)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.OutboundMessageContext.commitStream(OutboundMessageContext.java:811)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.writeEntity(ClientRequest.java:546)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:227)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:667)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:664)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:424)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:664)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:424)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:333)
    at com.fca.oslcbridge.vst.client.VSTServicesImpl.getVSTTAPattern(VSTServicesImpl.java:59)
    at com.oslcbridge.fca.resource.TAPatternResource.createTAPattern(TAPatternResource.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:384)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:342)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1030)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: /////////this is my calling function////try {
   TAPattern taPattern = vstServicesImpl.getVSTTAPattern(taPatternCon);
   testScriptService.updateTaPattern(taPattern);
   ObejctConversion.copyProperties(vstPatternCon, taPattern);
  } catch (IOException e) {

Comment: Looking at the stacktrace, it said you already opened and committed so you can't set the header. I think the connection is made at line ` Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);`.

Comment: I also tried  for replacing   Response response = invocationBuilder.header("Content-Type", "application/xml")
    .post(Entity.entity(vstpattern, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML));
  to Response response = invocationBuilder.post(Entity.entity(vstpattern, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML));

Comment: @MinhKieu Can you see my comment...please suggest

Comment: One problem in your code is that you are reading response after closing it -
 this line `response.readEntity(TAPattern.class);` should be before `response.close();`

Comment: Try Vikas suggestion to see if it make any difference.

Comment: @VikasSachdeva  not written response.close() anywhere in my code

Comment: @MinhKieu not written response.close() anywhere in code.

Comment: @VikasSachdeva invocationBuilder.header("Content-Type", "application/xml")
            .post(Entity.entity(vstpattern, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)); if I write above code ..does not catch response then "Server Timeout Exception occurs"

Comment: @MinhKieu invocationBuilder.header("Content-Type", "application/xml")
            .post(Entity.entity(vstpattern, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)); if I write above code ..does not catch response then "Server Timeout Exception occurs"

Comment: @Rishi - the bottom 2 lines `response.close();
    return response.readEntity(TAPattern.class);` You should not close the response until you read the entity.

Comment: @MinhKieu i removed response.close(); in updated code and does not catch response just call invocationBuilder simply but it gives server "timeout exception"

Comment: @RishiSalunkhe Please try reading the response using `response.readEntity(TAPattern.class);` and then close the response using `response.close();` and let us know the result.